# Databricks Api to update permissions of a directory is not working properly

Tags: api, databricks

Below api is not working properly, any idea what could be an issue?
https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/permissions.html#operation/get-directory-permissions

- PATCH /permissions/directories/{directory_id}

I tried to do the following and got weird results:

a. Using an api, i assigned a directory to a group named test_contributor with level "CAN_EDIT" and it worked fine

```
    json={
        "access_control_list": [
            {"group_name": group_name, "permission_level": level}
        ]
    },
```

b. I deleted the group test_contributor using delete groups api and created group test_contributor again and ran update permissions, this time it didn't assign it to the group and gave success response.

c. I repeated step b again and this time update permissions gave me an error saying that the group test_contributor doesn't exists but i can see it exists.